# After updatimg to bullseye enter did not work on login screen

Tags: debian, kde, login

Yesterday I tried to update buster to bullseye. All work as expected until I reboot my laptop.
Booting is working, start kde, invite me to insert password, but, enter did not working. So I could not input password.
What I discover:

1. Enter did not work with another keyboard.
2. Enter did not work on
   numpad.
3. Enter work in grub menu.
4. Enter work in console.

Help me, please.

Comment: Try a different login manager?

Comment: Yes, after researching I change sddm to lightdm.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of doing things, I could up wireless connection, depoy missed firmware, remove some outdated packages. Dunno what from this worked, but sddm start receive enter input and just freeze after login.
Changing to lightdm solve problem.